# How to refresh a window in appcelerator?

Tags: ios, json, image, video, appcelerator

I am developing a ios mobile app.In that mobile app I am showing the gallery. I created gallery in grid format with the help of JSON data.and also i provide a edit icon on that all images and video's of the gallery.if user click on edit icon the image is to be deleted.after that remaining images and video only show in grid format.so to get the non deleted images and videos in grid format we need to refresh the window. so can any one tell me how to refresh the current window in appcelerator ?

Comment: which controller are you using for grid?

Answer (score 0):

This would be an excellent case for Alloy's data binding:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding

If you're not using Alloy or for some reason do not want to use Collections to store your JSON data, then you will need to wrap the code where you render the icons in a function. When something changes/deletes you will have to call this function which should start with calling `removeAllChildren()` on the parent view which it will add the icons to.